# unsigned and signed data comparison and their representation in memory

Tags: c, binary

```
unsigned short int uwVal1=-10;short int wVal2=-10;
if(uwVal1==wVal2)
printf("Something");
```

What i know as per my knowledge is that whenever unsigned type is compared with signed type ....signed will convert it to unsigned for the moment. So by that logic...above code should print "Something".

if i do like this...

```
    printf("%u",wVal2);
```

it prints 4294967286!...number which is much greater than short int max +range i.e.65535. 
unsigned value of -10 will be 65526. Is the logic is different from what i think?

Comment: Try using `printf("%hu",wVal2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the logic is different from what you think.

The logic is explained fully by STL's video on [The Usual Arithmetic Conversions](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n).

(In the comparison, *both sides* are promoted to `int`, so you're comparing 65526 and -10.)